# Detect DataInputStream end of stream

Tags: java, arrays, networking, packet, datainputstream

I'm working on the server for a game right now. The server's packet reading loop is blocking, and typically waits until a packet is received to continue through the loop. However, if the client disconnects, the DataInputStream returns a single byte (-1) and the loop is executed in rapid succession, as is expected. However, I don't use the DataInputStream's read() method to read one byte at a time, I use the read(byte[]) method to read them all at once into a byte array. As such, I can't easily detect if the stream is returning a single byte valued at -1.

**Possible Solution:** I could check if the first byte of the array is -1, and if so loop through the array to see if the rest of the array is nothing but zeroes. Doing this seems extremely inefficient however, and I feel that it would affect performance as client count increases.

Here's a simplified version of my packet-reading loop:

```
while (!thread.isInterrupted() && !isDisconnected())
{
    try
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[26];
        data = new byte[26];

        input.read(data);

        //Need to check if end of stream here somehow
        Packet rawPacket = Packet.extractPacketFromData(data); //Constructs packet from the received data

        if(rawPacket instanceof SomePacket)
        {
            //Do stuff with packet
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        disconnectClient(); //Toggles flag showing client has disconnected
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look at `readFully` btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding of [`read(byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#read-byte:A-) is incorrect. It doesn't set a value in your array to `-1`.

The Javadoc says:

> **Returns:**
>   the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or `-1` if there is no more data because the end of the stream has been reached.

You need to check the return value:

```
int bytesRead = input.read(data);
if (bytesRead == -1)
{
  // it's end of stream
}
```

As a side note, even when just reading data normally, you do need to check the number of bytes read was the number of bytes you requested.  The call to `read` is not guaranteed to actually fill your array.

You should take a look at [`readFully()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFully-byte:A-) which does read fully, and throws an `EOFException` for end of stream:

> Reads some bytes from an input stream and stores them into the buffer array b. The number of bytes read is equal to the length of b.
>   This method blocks until one of the following conditions occurs:
>
> - `b.length` bytes of input data are available, in which case a normal return is made.
> - End of file is detected, in which case an `EOFException` is thrown.
> - An I/O error occurs, in which case an `IOException` other than `EOFException` is thrown.